# from `const now = new Date()`, how can I verify that I am before or equal a particular date at a given timezone and hour?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, momentjs, date-nfs

I have a timezone map with publishing hour in the local zone with news that must define when they should be published on a date using a date picker.

This is a new news `article` that is initialized with the following:

- `{ timeZoneId: 'Europe/Paris, releaseHour: 9, publishingDateTime: undefined }` // 9 is the hour GMT+1

I want to know how can I from `const now = new Date()`, verify if this article should be 
published today or the next day, the criteria are:

- Is `now` before `releaseHour`? (is 9am GMT+1 in paris already passs or not)
- If yes, then we should offer the next release slot at 9am GMT+1 + 1 day
- If no, then we should use the release slot at 9am the same day

How is this possible?

This is how I have tried:

```
import { isBefore, isEqual } from 'date-fns';
import { utcToZonedTime } from 'date-fns-tz';

export const getNextPublishingDateTime = (now, timeZoneId, releaseHour) => {
  const zoned = utcToZonedTime(now, timeZoneId);
  const releaseTime = new Date(zoned.toISOString());
  releaseTime.setHours(releaseHour, 0, 0, 0);
  if (isBefore(zoned, releaseTime) || isEqual(zoned, releaseTime)) {
    console.log('before');
    return releaseTime;
  }
  releaseTime.setDate(releaseTime.getDate() + 1);
  console.log('after');
  return releaseTime;
};
```

But the hour returned by `utcToZonedTime` is not +01:00 offset, instead it is a date at my offset.

I have tried some other ideas, using `moment-tz` and vanilla `Date`, I found this task a bit complicated and hope to find help with the JS community as this look to be a normal date comparaison.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Intl object and [*formatToParts*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat/formatToParts#Browser_compatibility) method to get the current time in any supported timezone using IANA [representative locations](https://www.iana.org/time-zones). It's [reasonably well supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat/formatToParts#Browser_compatibility).

E.g.

```js
function getHour(date, loc) {
  let d = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-EN", {
    hour: 'numeric',
    hour12: false,
    timeZone: loc
  });
  return d.formatToParts(date)[0].value;
}

let loc = 'Europe/Paris';
let now = new Date();
console.log(`The current hour in ${loc} is ${getHour(now, loc)}.`);
```

The above is just for illustration, there should be validation of input and return values.